# Emitting avro format from pipes in Hadoop

Tags: c++, hadoop, pipe, avro

I have to program in C++ for Hadoop and I deal with a complex structure of output value.
Unfortunately I can't figure out how to emit this structure in Avro format in MapReduce.
There are some writers like DataFileWriter and they work well for me. But it all doesn't make sense in terms of HDFS.

How I emit the structure now:

```
IOSerializer serializer;
context.emit(key, serializer.toString(output));
```

This custom toString method I wrote myself (sorry for the name, I'm totally from the Java world).
This is just a custom serialization into String. I really want some interoperability here and decided to use Avro.

This is the code to write Avro into the file:

```
avro::DataFileWriter<fusion_solve::graph> dfw("test.bin", schema);
dfw.write(output);
dfw.close();
```

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
IOSerializer serializer;
context.emit(serializer.toAvro(key, output));
```

For the moment I will be happy to get just plain JSON string as output, to convert it later.
The other option for me is writing custom RecordWriter in Java. But which type of input data should I use in this case, JSON?